# USB hub assigning random com ports when Windows 7 PC or USB Hub are rebooted

Tags: windows-7, port, usb, hub

I have four hardware devices that are plugged in through a self powered USB hub.  Currently the devices are assigned COM1 COM2 COM3 COM4 through device manager as hoped.  However, when rebooting the PC or USB hub sometimes the assigned COM ports in device manager will switch and mix about in a random order.

I need these devices to always be recognized in a particular COM port so my software will account for this.

Does anyone know if there is a way to assign static COM ports on a USB self powered hub so that if the USB hub or PC is powered off or rebooted the same COM port will automatically be assigned back to the relevant hardware device?

I am using a Star Tech 4 Port USB USB2004EXT2 and Windows 7 64 bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these USB -> Serial devices? Are they all the same?

Comment: No, they are not the same device. They are two types of devices.  In this case there are 2 of each e.g. 2 x 2.