# How to fix the COM port name for USB serial port in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, putty, serial-port

I am using USB-to-Serial port adapter in Windows 7 notebook. The model as seen in `Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers` is named as `Profilic USB-to-Serial Comm Port`. When remove the adapter from USB port and hibernate and then wake-up and reinsert the adapter it keeps changing between `COM3` and `COM4`. I am always using the same USB port. Just now, for example, it is `COM3` and advanced properties for the device allows changing the port setting but it says `COM4` is "in use".)

I am using PuTTY as my terminal program. If I guess or remember the `COM` port number incorrectly I need to restart PuTTY. It is also burdensome to do the mouse clicking circus to get the port number before starting PuTTY session. The state of my work-flow makes me feel like an idiot.

**Question:** Is there a way to lock the COM port in automated fashion (without needing to click click click all over the places with the mouse) so that when I reinsert the USB-to-serial port adapter, the port selection is always the same?

**Work-around** My plan B is to have two identical PuTTY sessions except for the `COM` number; run a short cut to a script that in some fashion detects which port number is valid and run PuTTY with that session (command line option `-load <session-name>`). However, I would like to find more general solution in case I want to access the serial port in some other ways (using some other application).

Related (unanswered), almost duplicate question (hardware configuration different, these two questions might have a little bit different answers): [USB hub assigning random com ports when Windows 7 PC or USB Hub are rebooted](https://superuser.com/questions/583495/usb-hub-assigning-random-com-ports-when-windows-7-pc-or-usb-hub-are-rebooted)