# If I plug a two serial devices into usb adapters both into a single USB hub will my computer see two different COM ports?

Tags: serial-port, usb

Hopefully a simple question but I couldn't quite find the answer myself. I'm writing a program in C++ that will, among other things, need to control two devices that are run by serial port. This program will be running on a laptop with NO serial ports, and possibly not enough USB ports. So I am going to have to use serial to USB adapters and worst case scenario I will have to plug both adapters into a single USB hub.

As far as I understand it when I plug the adapter right into a USB port then my computer, and thus my code, just sees that as a serial device, so that's good. But I'm not sure what will happen if I go through a USB hub. I think it would work but I'm not positive, and unfortunately I do not have the equipment on hand to test right now (sadly I am having to write much of this program without constant access to the devices it will be controlling, not my choice).

So if anyone can confirm one way or the other that would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Rather trivial for *you* to get an accurate answer to this question.  This hardware is dirt-cheap, just buy another set.  The hardware is never the problem, the quality of the USB drivers always is.

Comment: It's not a personal project so I'd rather not spend personal money on it. They project sponsor has the hardware, I just don't currently have access to it but am trying to get as far as I can until I get full access. It's definitely not an opportune situation but it's not really in my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each USB-serial adapter will show up as its unique **/dev/ttyUSBx** device.

Note: there are multi-port adapters, i.e. a USB hub with several USB-serial adapters all housed in one enclosure.  I use a few 4-port devices (one USB B-port, four FTDI chips and four DB9 connectors).
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The driver will do the choice whether to reassign the same or other. You can also see here [USB hub assigning random com ports when Windows 7 PC or USB Hub are rebooted](https://superuser.com/questions/583495/usb-hub-assigning-random-com-ports-when-windows-7-pc-or-usb-hub-are-rebooted)

Comment: Can you expand on this in a way that adds to the already [accepted answer](http://superuser.com/a/821505/461558)?