# assigning com ports to usb ports of a usb hub

Tags: usb, ports, hub, com

I am starting to automate my lab and for that I need to connect 8 devices to my computer (not enough USB ports). All of them can communicate through a virtual com port. My question is that if I connect 8 devices through a USB hub, will I be able to assign 8 virtual com ports?

Comment: Yes.  See https://superuser.com/questions/821504/if-i-plug-a-two-serial-devices-into-usb-adapters-both-into-a-single-usb-hub-will

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise going this way.

It would be much simpler to get another USB hub. If you don't have a free
USB port, you can piggy-back one hub on the other and
have up to 127 USB devices connected to the computer this way.

As the power available on one USB port is limited, ensure that both USB hubs are
self-powered (meaning have separate power cables).